# gnome-sushi doesn't work after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 19.04, previews, gnome-sushi

gnome-sushi doesn't work after upgrade to 19.04.
I tried to reinstall it, but no effect.
After pressing space bar I catch this errors in `dmesg`

```
[116847.106625] sushi-start[5011]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f5364b2505f sp 00007ffd5aca7a90 error 6 in libgjs.so.0.0.0[7f5364aec000+66000]
[116847.106632] Code: 00 e8 55 f7 00 00 4c 8b 04 24 48 8d 0d 4d 47 03 00 48 8b 7c 24 18 89 c6 31 d2 31 c0 e8 1a a0 fc ff 48 8b 7b 18 e8 a1 8d 00 00 <41> c7 07 01 00 00 00 e9 82 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b bb 78 01
```

Comment: try purging it instead of removing it and run `sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean` and also updates after you do so.